# I was searching the position of Sirius in Stellarium; then I saw some weird shapes

Tags: star, stellarium

What does it represent? I have also tried another skymap but on those there were no shapes like this. I have also straight light lines. What does it represent>

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0kaL.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Possibly starlink satelittes?

Answer (score 1):

Those are imaging artefacts that have not been “cleaned up.” Stellarium uses actual images of the night sky, but these must be processed to remove satellite trails (as mentioned by *Starship is go for launch*), asteroid trails, detector noise, etc. The red square around TYC 445-6-1 could be the field of view of a specific camera onboard a satellite, or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the previous answer that the trails correspond to image artifacts.

As you may notice in the first image, there are also some dark squares in the image, probably due to different background levels before the combination of images.