# Mysterious Object In The Sky

Tags: identify-this-object

On Stellarium (https://stellarium-web.org), I found this mysterious object floating in the sky.
It is at 6h40m29s,-13º23'30" on the equatorial grid.
It is surrounded by HD 47366, HD 47182, and HD 47667.
The closest well-known star is Sirius.

[image]

Can anyone explain what this is?

Comment: I also found strange orange thing near TYC 5968-2733-1.

Comment: The object in that post https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/53267/16685 is nowhere near Sirius

Comment: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/48645/what-have-I-encountered-here better duplicate

Comment: This question is perfectly valid. Sirius is the star in question here, neither of the other posts cover it.

Comment: @DekoRevinio Not sure who you're replying to, but it doesn't appear the question is about Sirius, only that the object in question (the image artifact) appears near it.

Comment: @GrapefruitIsAwesome ah, I see what you mean now. My apologies.